# updating a feature class from a feature layer in arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm writing a python script to find error in attribute codes in a feature class. In order to find some of these errors I need to use the select by location tool. But, the select by location tool only takes layers as inputs so I have to create a layer from the feature class. So if I update the error code field in the layer file how do I then populate the error code field in the original feature class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

One can use the [arcpy data access toolbox's UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm#C_GUID-5CBF0F12-3B31-41AC-A525-65829523F692), which is newer and faster than the original form of the UpdateCursor I initially described.

```
error_code=-1
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('lulcTV', ['error_field', 'VALUE']) as coverCSR:
    for tree in coverCSR:
        species = tree[1]  # returns'VALUE'. Not really needed, but good to know about
        tree[0] = error_code  # sets first requested field, "error_field"
        coverCSR.updateRow(tree)
```

---

**Original answer**

Seems like you could use an UpdateCursor. Example:

```
coverCSR=arcpy.UpdateCursor('lulcTV')
error_code=-1
for tree in coverCSR:
    species=tree.getValue('VALUE') # not really needed, but good to know about
    tree.setValue('error_field', error_code)
    coverCSR.updateRow(tree)
```

This iterates over all rows, one by one.